# Squash in git rebase with "git merge --squash" style commit message?

Tags: git, git-merge, rebase, squash

When using `git merge --squash`, the commit messages will be pre-populated with a full `git log` of the merged commits; When using `git rebase -i` to squash commits, the commit message doesn't contain as much information.

Is it possible to get the same prepopulated commit message when rebasing?

Comment: That description seems to me to be backwards: when you use `squash` in interactive rebase, the editor comes up on a file containing *all* the information, and when you use `git merge --squash`, the editor comes up on a file containing less information. The actual information depends on `merge.log`; if it's set to, say, 10, you'll get up to ten `git log --oneline` subject lines.

Comment: (Other than that, your answer covers a perfectly sensible way to do what you want.)

Comment: @torek It is strange then. For me, `git merge --squash` has always yielded verbose messages and `git rebase -i` squashing the reduced one. I'll have to check if it is a matter of project configuration as made by the source repository I guess...

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the `squash` operator in the `git rebase -i` interface, we can use `exec git merge --squash` to get the intended effect. For example, instead of

```
pick 31988313 master
pick 42983473 first commit of squash
squash 231adf41 second commit of squash
...
squash e32b1fa4 last commit of squash
pick 1ad9e130 more commits
```

We can use

```
pick 31988313 master
drop 42983473 first commit of squash
drop 231adf41 second commit of squash
...
drop e32b1fa4 last commit of squash
exec git merge --squash e32b1fa4
pick 1ad9e130 more commits
```

The downside is that additional care has to be taken to not accidentally drop too many commits.